# Want to open MS word,Excel,PowerPoint from ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, ole

I want to make an website which gives training of Office Automation (MS Word,Excel,PowerPoint) for that, suppose i have an webpage which displays an question regarding MS Word, let question is  "Type word 'stackoverflow' in word document and make it bold?" Webpage will have an button called "Start Practice Test" when user click on this it will open MS Office Word on his PC and he will do accordingly what is in Question once he done with it user will again come to page and click on "End Test" when he click on end test whatever he did in that documennt is to be monitor and marks given accordingly.

I can do same thing in Windows application using OLE scripting but i want to do same with web based system, i searched a lot and i came to know that OLE will not work with web based system.

So is there any **open source** tool/API/Plugin  which will do same think.?

Comment: The same compared to what? Allow cross-browser way to run arbitrary scripts on local machine?

Comment: Don't use Office Interop for this. It can't be properly run from an ASP.NET application.

Answer (score 0):

This is much more different than the way you thought about it. You have two options:

1. Simulation of MS Word via a rich client framework
2. Using some Active-X control

Both 1 & 2 are not robust and take a lot of effort.

A better solution is a standalone application (exe) which talks to web services as needed (exchanging data at background).

Comment: after posting this question i thought about the same as u said (about standalone application (exe) which talks to web services as needed) [Here is link of second question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239211/execute-methods-in-windows-application-from-asp-net-page)..is that idea is correct..can you help in that.

Comment: @Amogh: I checked it. Unfortunately you are far from what you want to do and I doubt you get the help at SOF.